# Serializing an iframe's content from head to toe with HTML special characters within Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, serialization

I'm using an iframe as an html editor and I load its content by setting iframe's src attribute. Afterwards, I turn on iframe's `designMode` so I can edit the loaded html content.

Once user is done, he'll press a save button and I'll try to retrieve the edited html content and sending it to the server. It's just that I need the full content of the iframe, including the `<html>` and `<!doctype>`. The problem I've faced is that when I retrieve the iframe's content, its embedded javascript code has encoded all `<` into `&lt;`, even within Javascript code!

Here's how I wrote my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="about: blank"></iframe>
<button>Save to textarea</button>
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $iframe = $("iframe");
  var $iframeBody = $iframe.contents().find('body');
  $iframeBody.html('<scr'+'ipt>var x = 1 < 2;</scr'+'ipt>&lt;&gt;&amp;');
  $iframe.contents().prop('designMode','on');
  $("button").click(function() {
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var html = serializer.serializeToString($iframe.contents()[0])
    $("textarea").val(html);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing the save button will output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>var x = 1 &lt; 2;</script>&lt;&gt;&amp;
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the result is unusable because there's no way I can tell apart which `&lt;` should be replaced with `<` (unless the text is parsed)!!

Does anyone have any idea how to retrieve the contents of an iframe completely without ruining it?

Comment: Have you tried `$iframeBody.text(...)` instead of `$iframeBody.html(...)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - you don't need `XMLSerializer`. You try to serialize `html` like `xml`. I think you need a `html`. So it will be better to use `$iframe.contents().get(0).documentElement.outerHTML`. This will return whole `html` of iframe without `doctype`. For doctype you can use this function:

```
function getDoctypeString (doc) {
    var doctypeNode = doc.doctype;
    if (!doctypeNode) {
        return '';
    }
    return "<!DOCTYPE "
         + doctypeNode.name
         + (doctypeNode.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + doctypeNode.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!doctypeNode.publicId && doctypeNode.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (doctypeNode.systemId ? ' "' + doctypeNode.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
}
```

And all [together](http://jsbin.com/moxocaseqa/1/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <iframe src="about: blank"></iframe><br>
  <button>Save to textarea</button><br>
  <textarea cols=55 rows=10></textarea>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      function getDoctypeString(doc) {
        var doctypeNode = doc.doctype;
        if (!doctypeNode) {
          return '';
        }
        return "<!DOCTYPE " + doctypeNode.name + (doctypeNode.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + doctypeNode.publicId + '"' : '') + (!doctypeNode.publicId && doctypeNode.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (doctypeNode.systemId ? ' "' + doctypeNode.systemId + '"' : '') + '>';
      }
      var $iframe = $("iframe");
      var $iframeBody = $iframe.contents().find('body');
      var $textarea = $("textarea");
      $iframeBody.html('<scr' + 'ipt>var x = 1 < 2;</scr' + 'ipt>&lt;&gt;&amp;');
      $iframe.contents().prop('designMode', 'on');
      $("button").click(function() {
        var iframeDocument = $iframe.contents().get(0);
        $textarea.val(getDoctypeString(iframeDocument) + iframeDocument.documentElement.outerHTML);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, little late. I have an ajax function and the form is in the iframe. So, can i put the ajax script in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html of the iframe without any character substitution by using:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Here's a working [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/geweyo/11/edit?html,js,output).

The reason you cannot find the doctype of the iframe might be because the iframe does not have a doctype.

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) adding a doctype to an iframe is optional.

I took a look at the iframe in Firefox v33 and Chrome v39 and it did not have a doctype. Only the owner document had a doctype. Try it out in your browser with this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/riqoho/2/edit?html,js,console).

Also, doctypes are used [for legacy reasons](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#syntax-doctype), and if you are worried about older browsers, you can just prepend a doctype tag to your html string:

```
var html = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
html = '<!DOCTYPE html>' + html;
$("textarea").val(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode HTML code by doing this:

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(text).text();
alert(decoded);
```